# Firebase Realtime Database - multiple users accesing same portion of data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design, nosql, database-schema

I'm using Firebase (Realtime Database) and Firebase Authentication in my mobile app (to create products and take orders).

So far, I'm able to login and access data of each user based on its `uid`. This is the current schema:

```
database-id
  - products
    - productId (generated by firebase something like: -M7Z0pL3CVtYxah7MwQz)
      - ownerId: uid (available after login)
```

I need to be able to have multiple users to access same data, **how this can be accomplished in a noSQL database like this?**

I was thinking something like this:

```
database-id
 - users
   - uid
     - accountId
 - products
   - accountId
      - productId (generated by firebase something like: -M7Z0pL3CVtYxah7MwQz)
        - ownerId: uid (available after login)
```

this way, after login with that uid I can request like this:
`https://database-id/users/<uid>.json` to get `accountId` and then, I can request products like this: `https://database-id/products/<accountId>.json`.

Any thoughts? Or a better way to implement this approach of multiple users accessing same account data on a noSQL schema?

Comment: Your logic of mapping a user to an account sounds fine to me. But beyond that it is really hard to say anything generic as NoSQL data models typically evolve with the use-cases they support. If you're new to this I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) and [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) (the last one of for Firestore but most information applies for all NoSQL databases).

Comment: If you have more specific use-cases like the one of mapping UID to account ID, please post additional, concrete questions about each of those, and what problem you have with the data model you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic of mapping a user to an account sounds fine to me. But beyond that it is really hard to say anything generic as NoSQL data models typically evolve with the use-cases they support.

If you're new to this I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) and [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) (the last one of for Firestore but most information applies for all NoSQL databases).